# QGIS polygonize tool not working

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, layers, polygon-creation

I am having a problem using QGIS ver 2.10.1 Pisa.  I am trying to use the polygonize function on a raster .tif image, and it runs, but only produces a thin sliver of polygons at the top, then stops working or loading.  Has anyone encountered this problem, or know how to solve it?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details, such as a gdalinfo report and screenshot of the raster and your polygonize parameters.